# how to select combobox item based on values on other widget in pyqt

Tags: mapping, qcombobox, qlineedit

I have a lineEdit and a combobox.

I have data as below

```
---------------------
|ID    | DisplayName|
---------------------
|100   | OneHundred |
|150   | OneFifty   |
|25    | TwendyFive |
---------------------
```

I added DisplayNames as items in combobox.

I want to do as below

when i enter 100 in lineedit, then "OneHundred" item to be selected in combobox
when i enter 25 in lineedit, then "TwentyFive" item to be selected in combobox

it should work like this.

Can any one suggest a method to achieve this....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution what i asked for.

I used userData to achieve this. Added items to combobox as below

```
ID = ['100','150','25']
Name = ['OneHundred','OneFifty','TwentyFive']

for i in xrange(3):

    cmbobox.addItem(Name[i],ID[i])
```

For lineedit textchange i wrote as below

```
index = comobox.findData(lineedit.text())
combobox.setCurrentIndex(index)
```